# What lego set is this? Possibly a pirate ship?

Tags: set-identification

my wife picked up this lego set at a garage sale. The owner claimed it was a ship, perhaps a pirate ship, and that the set was complete. It does have something resembling a bow, and several tall poles, but no sails, which sounds suspiciously non-ship like. The most distinct piece is something like a black bicycle chain / rope ladder on a gear, attached to what looks like a 4-piston engine. There's another smaller chain as well. The entire set is in a beige / brown / black color scheme. Images below - can someone help me identify this?

(I already tried searching for the piece on rebrickable, but could not find it under any description I could think of.)

[image: Full set]
[image: Chain or ladder]

Comment: It's the Wright Flyer:
http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4222843.pdf

It's the rule of posting on SE - I found it almost immediately after hitting submit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a ship alright.. a heavier than air airship: [Wright Flyer](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=10124-1).

Quite a fun, if rickety. build.